# How do I replace parts of a text file with user-inputted data with PHP if the user-inputted data is a copy of existing data in the form?

Tags: php

My knowledge of programming is limited to object-oriented languages, so bear with me.

I've created a form for users to vote on their favorite professors. One column of the table should display the professor's name, and the other column should display how many people voted for them.

If a professor's name hasn't been entered before, then a new row is created, and that professor has a vote count of 1. If a professor's name *has* been entered before, then the vote count should be incremented.

I use commas to differentiate between name and vote count.

I'm most likely doing everything wrong here, but this is what I've made thus far. It does not work because, like I said, I have absolutely no knowledge of PHP.

```
<?php

    $name = $_POST["name"];

    $file = fopen("vote.txt", "r+");

    $copy = false;

    foreach($file as $row){
        list($nameOrig,$countOrig) = explode(',', $row);
        if($nameOrig == $name){
            $countNew = $countOrig + 1;
            preg_replace($countOrig,$countNew,$string);
            $copy = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if($copy == false){
        fwrite($file, $name);
        fwrite($file, ',');
        fwrite($file, '1');
    }

    fclose($file);

?>
```

Sample file:

```
Doe,1
Smith,3
Clark,1
John,8
```

Warnings:

```
Warning: fopen(vote.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /index.php on line 20 
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /index.php on line 24 
Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /index.php on line 37 
Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /index.php on line 38 
Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /index.php on line 39 
Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /index.php on line 40 
Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /index.php on line 41 
Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /index.php on line 44
```

I know for a fact vote.txt is in the right location because /vote.txt shows me the file.

Comment: get value, use `fopen`, then change value(something like: `$value = $file + 1;`), then overwrite file with changed value, something like: `fwrite($value);`

Comment: @DjordjeVujicic wouldn't this just append an extra field, which is what I'm trying to avoid? As in, if two people enter Doe as a professor then Doe appears on the list twice?

Comment: Oh I didn't read the code well... I thought you were only writing to file but not reading it... sry

Comment: Change `$name = _POST["name"];` for  `$name = $_POST["name"];`

Comment: @HeribertoJuarez it is changed, just a typo while asking the question

Comment: Don't use a text file for this, using a DB will be much easier and cleaner. That being said for us to debug this code you will need to be clearer about `It does not work`, where does it fail, what does it currently do?

Comment: Alright, Could you please provide a sample of what could be in your txt file ?

Comment: @chris85 All of the warnings appear to be involved with invalid arguments for foreach() and fwrite(). Also, vote.txt cannot be opened with fopen() even though www.url.com/vote.txt functions. Not sure if fixing this would cause my script to work though. For all I know it's written wrong.

Comment: @HeribertoJuarez updated the question to illustrate a sample file

Comment: Can you update the question with the warnings, permissions and filesystem structure (where `vote.txt` is located and where the executing script is running from) ?

Comment: @chris85 Edited. New to this whole thing so did I basically confirm I don't even have permission to read/write? I don't actually own this server; it's owned by my university, but I'm the one who has access to edit this specific URL.

Comment: Yup, `$file` is `FALSE` because permission is denied `if($copy == false){` is matched so you get 5 more (should be 3 based on the code here) warnings about the `$file` not being a resource (because it is false).

Answer (score 0):

I created a php script that does the job, even though it's not recommended to store data in a txt file you can still do it.

All the code I wrote currently works if you put it all in a single php file, Here it is:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name'])){ //if post name is set it means vote button was pressed
    $name = $_POST["name"]; //get name in the input field
    $file = fopen("vote.txt", "r+"); //open the file, in this case the txt file must be located in the same folder as this php file
    $fileContent = file_get_contents("vote.txt"); //get current content of txt file
    $teachers = (explode("\n",$fileContent)); //file has a line break (\n) at the end of every vote so create an element in an array called teachers for every line break
    $exists = false; //for future use
    $valueMatch; //if teacher exists save the string of his name and vote count in this variable
    foreach($teachers as $key => $value){ //check if teacher exists
        $parts = explode(",", $value); //create an array of items containing the name and votes of a record
        if($parts[0]==$name){ //$parts[0] contains the name of the current teacher, if matches with the name in the input it means it exists
            $exists = true; //for future use
            $valueMatch = $value; //value that the loop had at the moment of the match
        }
    }
    if($exists){ //if teacher exists
        $parts = explode(",", $valueMatch);
        $curentVotes = (int)$parts[1]; //put current votes in an int variable
        $newStr = $parts[0] . ", " . (++$curentVotes); //new string will contain the same string with a vote added
        $fileContent =  str_replace($valueMatch, $newStr, $fileContent); //the new file content //change the old vote for the new vote
        fwrite($file, $fileContent); //rewrite the file with the new vote
        echo "You voted for teacher " . $name . ". Current teacher votes: " . $curentVotes; //print feedback message
    }else{ //doesn't exist so add to the list
        $txt = $name . ", 1"; //teacher name plus comma and vote number of 1
        $myfile = file_put_contents('vote.txt', $txt.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX); //append txt to the file
        echo "The teacher " . $name . " was added to the votes list. Current teacher votes: 1"; //print feedback message
    }
    fclose($file); //close file
}
?>
```

I tested the code and It worked very good.

**NOTES**

1. This may need improvements such as validate some stuff
2. You may encounter some problems in certain situations
3. It happend to me that while testing the code I had the txt file opened and when a record was added it was added at the caret position I had when I had the file opened
4. The script is case sensitive so in the records you could find Ana and ana as 2 different records even though they could refer to the same teacher

**UPDATE**

While cleaning the code I messed up a part and I wouldn't work and I posted like that but now It's fixed.

I hope it helps you, Greetings from Mexico!